# ESP8266 + NodeMCU Custom Build + WS2812.Init() causing reset

Tags: nodemcu

I am trying to get some ws2812 lights to work.  I am using

```
NodeMCU custom build by frightanic.com
    branch: 1.5.4.1-final
    commit: 1885a30bd99aec338479aaed77c992dfd97fa8e2
    SSL: false
    modules: adc,file,gpio,http,i2c,net,node,ow,rtctime,spi,tmr,uart,websocket,wifi,ws2812
 build  built on: 2017-05-11 11:48
 powered by Lua 5.1.4 on SDK 1.5.4.1(39cb9a32)
```

When I execute ws2812.init() the board resets with:

```
> =ws2812.init()

 ets Jan  8 2013,rst cause:2, boot mode:(3,7)

load 0x40100000, len 24560, room 16 
tail 0
chksum 0xb4
load 0x3ffe8000, len 2296, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x09
load 0x3ffe88f8, len 136, room 8 
tail 0
chksum 0x9d
csum 0x9d
```

I can call the ws2812.write and I see a signal on the output pin, however the timing is not correct and the lights don't work.

What am I doing wrong?  This is my first ESP8266 project so i feel a bit clueless.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try with builds from `master` (v2.1)?

Comment: That was it.  Works great with the master branch.  I just assumed "final" was some how more stable and I should stick with that.  I'll never get those hours back!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Working based on assumptions is tricky ;-) The general release process is documented at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/#releases. Specifics about that 1.5.x branch are at the top of its README at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/tree/1.5.4.1-final#no_entry-this-branch-is-frozen-at-the-last-commit-before-the-espressif-sdk-was-upgraded-to-20-no_entry (the cloud builder you used contains those hints).

Answer (score 0):

Those ESP8266 chips are very picky when it comes to which pins you can use. Putting a voltage on a pin or even just connecting a sensor output during bootup can cause problems like the one you mentioned. Try not to use GPIO 0, 2 or 15 like also discussed in [this](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/2414) post.

GPIO labels are not neccesarily the same as the pin labels on your board. So stay away from pins D3, D4 and D8.
[image]

Also when you start using the WiFi functionality even more pins become unusable. This can cause very weird behavior without proper error codes. So be aware of this. I will try to find out for you which pins you can still use when WiFi is enabled.